# data.table behaviour with row.names and updating

Tags: r, data.table

This question about data.table has 2 parts... :

First, the disappearing row.names in data.table. 
See code below: converting a dataframe to a data.table zaps the row.names. 
But even after adding the row.names as a field they are zapped during the conversion.
What am I doing wrong?

Second, the communicating data.tables.
See code below: if I make a new data.table, the old and the new one seems to be communicating.
In other words, they are different tables, but updating table 1 also updates table 2.
What am I doing wrong?

```
library(data.table)
library(stringr)

# part 1 - the zapped row.names...
data(mtcars)
dt=mtcars
dt$cars=row.names(dt) # add row.names as field
cars=dt$cars          # stores field as vector, as next step will zap it
dt=data.table(mtcars) # zaps field "cars"...
dt=cbind(dt,cars)

# part 2 - the communicating data.tables...
dt1=dt # make a new table
dt1[,cars:=str_replace(cars,"Valiant","Thingy")] # change something in the table
# now *both* tables have changed...

# try with data.frame
df=mtcars
df$cars=row.names(df)

df1=df
df1=transform(df1,cars=str_replace(cars,"Valiant","Thingy")) # works as expected
# now only df1  has changed.
```

Comment: You've asked two questions in one here so it's difficult to deal with.  The dup is more for part 2.  Part 1 could be a new question but what precisely do you mean by "zap" ?

Comment: Thanks for pointing me to that link. It is quite a bit of text. The summary is: use dt1=copy(dt) instead of dt1=dt.

Comment: The link does not provide insight [for me] on the first part of my question: the zapped row.names. With "zapped" i mean that there were row.names or a field, and that they disappeared after the data.table conversion. Sorry for asking two questions in one, indeed not very clever of me.

Comment: why are you storing the column of row.names in `dt` and then doing `dt <- data.table(mtcars)`? Shouldn't you be doing `dt <- data.table(dt)`? `mtcars` does not have the column `cars`...

Comment: @Arun: If I do data.table(cars), the row.names disappear. Therefore I add the cars column manually. But they disappear as well when I convert to data.table - that is the part I don't get.

Comment: You add `cars` to `dt` and then convert `mtcars` to a `data.table`. But `mtcars` doesn't have a column called `cars`... This is a very silly issue you've overlooked in your code. Please go through your code again.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### Part 1

**You have an error in your code.**

You use  `dt=data.table(mtcars)`, where based on your description
you meant to use:  `dt=data.table(dt)`
  or   `dt=data.table(mtcars, cars)`

In other words, as @Arun pointed out in the comments, you convert `mtcars` to a *new* `data.table` named `dt`, then modify `dt`.  You never made any modifications to `mtcars`.

### Part 2

You have only taken a shallow copy.  Have a look at `?copy` and the other question that Matt pointed you to.
`dt2 <- copy(dt1)`

Comment: +1 Just to pick up that `dt1=dt` just points the `dt1` symbol at the same data `dt` is pointing to (no shallow copy there). `shallow()` is where the vector of column pointers is copied but then each slot of `dt1` pointed to the same column vectors in `dt`.